# Rolling dice in a method chain

Tags: c#, functional-programming, random

I've been writing code for nearly 40 years now and am still not too old to learn and understand new things. Right now, my focus is a bit of OO with functional programming combined and C# with Linq is an excellent way to fool around with this.
I'm also practicing deferred execution and aggregating to make it really interesting. So I designed a dice roller. And to start, I begin by specifying various dice types:

```
public enum DiceType { D2 = 2, D3 = 3, D4 = 4, D6 = 6, D8 = 8, D10 = 10, D12 = 12, D20 = 20, D100 = 100 }
```

Very basic, actually. Each enum value just indicates the number of sides a die has. These values are very common, with the D2 (coin flip) and D6 (regular die) being the most well-known.
Next is a static class that can basically roll any dice, and will do this until infinity:

```
public static class Dice
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Roll()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        while (true) { yield return rnd.Next(1, 7); }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> Roll(this DiceType die)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        while (true) { yield return rnd.Next((int)die) + 1; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> RollX(this IEnumerable<int> rolls, int x = 3)
    {
        while (true) { yield return rolls.Take(x).Sum(i => i); }
    }
}
```

The `Roll()` method will be the stereotype die with six sides. Hardcoded, as someone might change the value for D6 to 8 and cause problems. This method will always roll a six-sided die.
But `Roll(this DiceType die)` is more interesting as it basically extends the DiceTyper enumeration. And it will roll that specific die into infinity so if I use `DiceType.D20.Roll()` then I will get an endless list of values between 1 and 20...
The third method `RollX()` is an even more interesting one. It will use the previous dice enumerator and take an X amount of values to sum them, before taking the next X amount of dice. By default, it will roll 3 times. And `DiceType.D6.Roll().RollX(5)` will roll 5 dice, each resulting in a value between 1 and 6, and add them to get values between 5 and 30, and a bell curve.
Next, two clock-related aggregators that will limit the amount of time allowed to keep rolling:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MaxTime<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, long totalMs)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!sw.IsRunning) { sw.Restart(); }
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < totalMs) { yield return item; }
        else { yield break; }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> MaxTicks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, long totalTicks)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!sw.IsRunning) { sw.Restart(); }
        if (sw.ElapsedTicks < totalTicks) { yield return item; }
        else { yield break; }
    }
}
```

The stopwatch class can be found in System.Diagnostics.
The principle is simple: it will do a deferred execution until the time is up, which can either be a matter of seconds or a matter of clock ticks.
As a final step, I want an aggregator to just add all the results:

```
public static SumTotal Total(this IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var result = new SumTotal();
    foreach (var i in data) { result.Add(i); }
    return result;
}
```

And this introduces this class:

```
public class SumTotal
{
    public long Sum { get; set; } = 0;
    public long Total { get; set; } = 0;
    public long Min { get; set; } = long.MaxValue;
    public long Max { get; set; } = long.MinValue;

    public SumTotal Add(long value)
    {
        Total++;
        Sum += value;
        if (Max < value) { Max = value; }
        if (value < Min) { Min = value; }
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"For {Total:#,##0} items, total of {Sum:#,##0}, average of {Sum * 1.0 / Total:#,##0.00} between {Min:#,##0} and {Max:#,##0}.";
}
```

So I get a total containing the number of rolls, the minimum and maximum values rolled and a total of all values and can calculate the average value rolled.
Now, to use it, all I have to do is define a rolling queue like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> D12Queue = DiceType.D12.Roll();
```

This generates a static variable from where I can just take an X amount of rolls. Simply using `D12Queue.Take(5)` will give me 5 random values between 1 and 12. This makes it practical to use in games where you'd need to emulate a dice roll.
So, is this a practical solution? I'm just training and learning new skills so I haven't thought about that aspect...

---

The latter dice queue is what my main focus will be. I can use this:
`var queue = DiceType.D6.Roll();` to generate a queue. And then:
`var roll = queue.First();` which will give a new dice roll with every call.
`var yahtzee = queue.Take(5);` to roll 5 dice and see if I rolled a Yahtzee.
`var highRoll = queue.RollX(5).Take(20).Max();` Which will roll 5 dice repeatedly for 20 times and return the highest value.
So basically, I made dice rolling part of Linq queries so I don't need to write loops if I need multiple rolls. I just take the number of required rolls from the queue.

Comment: I recently wrote a 41 part blog series on the subject of how to generalize the lessons of LINQ to representing randomness; you might find it interesting. Start here: https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/

Comment: I'm considering if the DiceType enum should be converted into a list of int constants and extend the Roll() method to the int type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just repeat what @Ron Klein said, dont put your dices into enum, the real set of all possible dices is much greater than what your enum offers.

Let me show how I think the Dice class would be better implemented:

```
class Dice : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int Sides;
    private int Shift;
    private Random Generator;

    public Dice(int sides, int shift, Random generator)
    {
        Sides = sides;
        Shift = shift;
        Generator = generator;
    }

    public Dice(int sides, int shift, int seed) : this(sides, shift, new Random(seed)) {}
    public Dice(int sides, int shift) : this(sides, shift, new Random()) {}
    public Dice(int sides, Random generator) : this(sides, 1, generator) {}
    public Dice(int sides) : this(sides, 1) {}
    public Dice(Random generator) : this(6, generator) {}
    public Dice() : this(6) {}

    public int Roll()
    {
        return Generator.Next(Sides) + Shift;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (true) yield return Roll();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can create whatever dice you want:

```
var d20 = new Dice(20);
var coin = new Dice(2);
var cube = new Dice(6);
var uncommon = new Dice(7);
var d0to5 = new Dice(6, 0);
var d15to30 new Dice(16, 15);
```

You can roll once

```
var roll = d20.Roll(); //1-20
```

Or you can roll N times

```
var sum = uncommon.Take(3).Sum(i => i); //3-21
```

Or you can even roll as many as the CPU can do in a certain amount of time/ticks

```
var rolls = cube.MaxTicks(250);
```

Also as mentioned by others, the Random class needs a seed and the default constructor seeds from current time. My Dice class implementation allow this default Random but also allows to inject Random instance seeded in a way out of scope of the Dice class.

```
var d20 = new Dice(20, new Random(myseed));
```

I have actualy added more constructors to simplify this and I have also added `Shift` property to the Dice as it seemd a waste to have +1 as constant, if it might be possible to have dices starting with zero or any other number.

```
var d20 = new Dice(20, 1, myseed);
```

Anyway I think that the `MaxTick` and `MaxTime` methods are quite controversial. One thing is they break SRP.
Good rule of thumb though is that methods should not instantiate objects and do some work (other that the work needed to instantiate those objects). They should do one or the other, but not both.
Other thing is I'm not sure they will fulfill their purpose as mentioned in comments under other answer.

Comment: Actually, no! I can use First() to get just one roll or Take() to get a number of rolls. By repeating calls to First(), I keep getting new rolls. The principle is that I defined a dice queue from where you can get as many dice rolls as you need. An infinite number of rolls to be used whenever needed.

Comment: Creating an infinite enumeration was my purpose here. It would be bad when someone called `DiceType.D20.Roll().Last();` as it would run forever. You're missing the point, though. I implemented it as an enumeration so you can get a list of rolls like `DiceType.D6.Roll().Take(5);` would give 5 values immediately. Not the sum of 5 values. Useful for a Yahtzee game.

Comment: Your MaxTicks() method is now limited to rolling dice. Mine can be used for any enumeration and will just break off enumeration when the time is up. You made a method with two functions, mine has just one.

Comment: @WimtenBrink ok I guess I missed that purpose. I edited a little to fit your needs. Basicaly keep the `MaxTicks` and `MaxTime` away as you did. but the `Dice` class now implements `IEnumerable<int>` so you can use it with those methods. Also added some convenience constructors.

Comment: Now, this is a Dice version I like. Do keep in mind that I want a Dice solution, not a Random replacement. So the shift parameter is not needed as they all start with 1. Even cards start at one. I also wonder if the Random generator should be a static variable in the class, so it is created once and reused for all dice objects. But what I like about the extension method is that you can replace DiceType by Int and thus use 12.Roll() to get a queue for rolling D12's.

Comment: And yex, MaxTicks and MaxTime are a bit controversial but I made them to allow time constraints on method chains handling enumerations. Adding MaxTime() to a Dice queue would basically force a game to be over as no more dice can be rolled after the amount of time. When the queue is generated when the game starts, the game would be nicely limited in the amount of game time.

Comment: @WimtenBrink I'm not sure that would be a good idea to share one Random object. It is a very simple RNG and it shows some patterns if you for example generate coordinates with it (rolling 2 dice repeatedly one after the other is kinda the same). But Maybe it would be enough for your case.

Comment: @WimtenBrink Also one shared static instance may be quite easy to guess what numbers it is going to generate based on the time at which you start the program. I've been thinking maybe you could have one static instance and use this to generate seeds for new Random instances that you will pass to each new Dice. This way it may still be a bit predictable, but the predictions will divert from real values very fast.

Comment: @WimtenBrink another option might be to use a mre sofisticated RNG (like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) then i guess it wouldn't be much of a problem to share just one instance of it...

Answer (score 8):

## `Random`

Don't `new` up a new instance of `Random` for each and every call of your methods. The reason for this is that the default seed used in the constructor is **not** random. Usually it's based on the current time, or something similar. This means that if you call the method many times at once, the random number generators might provide the same numbers.

Instead, create a single static instance that's used by all calls.

---

```
public static SumTotal Total(this IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var result = new SumTotal();
    foreach (var i in data) { result.Add(i); }
    return result;
}
```

The `linq` way of doing this is `data.Aggregate(new SumTotal(), (item, aggregate) => aggregate.Add(item))`.

Comment: That bug has been fixed in new versions of .NET, after only being in the platform for 19 years. But it is still a bad idea to make a new `Random` every time you need a new number.

Comment: The New() is called just once for every dice queue. And the method is used to create one queue for every dice needed and grab values from the queue whenever needed. So, not a problem to me.

Comment: The Total method is an aggregator method, similar to Aggregate, ToList and a few other methods. Using aggregators and understanding how they work are different things.

Comment: @WimtenBrink the point still stands, and if you are providing this code as a library, you don't have control about how it is called, or how often. Best to think ahead and don't make the mistakes that are easy to prevent.

Comment: If I do make a library out of it, it would include a static class with the various dice queues as static variables, depending on what it will be part off. The rest would basically become an internal class. This code by itself isn't meant to be a complete library. It needs more to be more practical.

Answer (score 5):

Nice code.

Some comments :)

### Too Defensive

You wrote:

> The `Roll()` method will be the stereotype die with six sides.
>   Hardcoded, as someone might change the value for D6 to 8 and cause
>   problems. This method will always roll a six-sided die.

What if someone changes the underlying value of D2 to 3? Won't that be a major surprise?

My take about this approach is: don't write idiot proof code, otherwise you'd be chasing your tail. Write code that an average programmer could understand.

In your code, there's a convention that the die enum name *has to be* the same as its underlying `int` value. That's a design decision you took. It's a valid design decision. Stick to it.

In addition, if, for some reason, you choose to change your implementation of the underlying enum value, you'll have to remember that the logic is also implemented, hard coded, in your `Roll()` method. In other words, you break DRY.

### O/CP

When you have an `enum` in your code, it should be a well defined, closed group of values that usually share something. The "closed" part is essential.

Take weekdays, for instance. There won't be any additional weekday. There's no eighth value that can be added. Therefore, we can have them as an `enum`.

Take card suites. There are only four of them. I think my point is clear.

When we declare an `enum`, we say something like: "these are the only values of this group."

However, in your code, you declare (only) the following values as possible die/dice:

2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100

What if someone would want to have your cool engine to be applied on a card suite? It's 13 cards in a suite. And you don't have 13 as a value in your `enum`.

In programming, there's a very important principle named [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). I think that your `enum` is not aligned with O/CP, because if you'd want to use your random engine on a "die" with 13 values, then you'd have to add `D13` to your `enum`, rebuild and redeploy your solution. When you're aligned with O/CP - you provide a way to extend your program ("open to extensions") without rebuilding it ("closed to modifications").

So maybe there's no need to wrap those values in an `enum` in the first place? Simply write a class that takes the number of edges the "die" has in its constructor, and you're done.

It's not as "pretty" as an `enum`, but it sure is more extensible.

### Deferred Execution

You write:

> The principle is simple: it will do a deferred execution until the
>   time is up, which can either be a matter of seconds or a matter of
>   clock ticks.

I'm not sure what you mean by that. It's not that the code runs on a different thread. Maybe I'm missing something because I haven't been coding in C# for a long while, but this code sure seems to be blocking.

I think that the added value of those methods (`MaxTime` and `MaxTicks`) is low, and it's pretty much up to the consuming developer to implement them as needed.

In addition to all that, there's sometime a confusion between wall-clock time (which is how things are implemented in your code) and processing time. In a multi-threaded program (or in a multi-processed system), your program, or your executing thread, is sometimes paused so that other processed/threads are executed.
Having this point in mind, you might end up executing far less iteration than expected.
Example: usually you get 10000 iterations in 300 ticks, but in a busy system you get only 500 under the same 300 ticks. The numbers are imaginary, but you get the idea.
For doing the actual measurements, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23182781/17772).

Again, I think that adding those measurements to your code somehow increases complexity and have a low value.

### Calculating Min/Max

It's mostly a matter of style, but I tend to use the SDK's provided functions when possible.
In your code:

```
if (Max < value) { Max = value; }
```

Can be replaced with:

```
Max = Math.Max(Max, value)
```

To me, this is easier to understand the intention of the code using the built-in `Math.Max()` method.

Cheers :)

Comment: Really? Math.Max instead avoiding unnecesary write? I mean `c=math.max(a,b)` why not. But `a=math.max(a,b)` why yes?

Comment: @slepic yes, IMO intention (or semantics), readability and consistency are stronger considerations than performance. There's a famous quote: _Premature optimization is the root of all evil_... If you profile your program and see that there's a performance issue - then (and only then) optimize your code.

Comment: I know what premature optimization is. But I would object that this isn't it.There is difference between premature optimization and awareness of performance aspects of your code (especialy in a lib it would be bad to ignore performance until some user of the lib reports performance issues, especialy if you could have seen it before you even started implementing it). And I would also object whether a less then + an assignment is less readable than Math.Max.Anyway I wouldn't have brought this up if you didn't bring this up. It was optimal and you suggest suboptimal for a little readability gain.

Comment: Fair enough. We both have our opinions. I even like the debate :)

Comment: The MaxTicks() and MaxTime() methods are useful for performance tests and to see how many rolls I can get within a certain amount of time. But if the dice queue is used for a game then it would add a time limit for the game. After e.g. 60 seconds, the queue would be "empty" and thus the game would be over. So the game gets a simple time limit...

Comment: As for cards and even a whole deck of cards, you could add them to the enum: `CardValue=13` and `DeckOfCards=52`. But the Roll() method might also just extend any integer... I choose the enum to be more descriptive. (And cards aren't dice!)

Comment: The deferred execution relates to the `yield return` which gets called whenever the next method in line asks for the next value. With the MaxTime and MaxTicks method, it will stop yielding values so that ends all rolls. Game over, basically...

Comment: @WimtenBrink in a game you will often want to make the timer accessible by the game state view layer. and so it might be better to have it in upper layer and use it to control how long you keep calling Roll(), instead of having to retrieve the timer from inside the roll queue which you actualy didn't make possible. In you implementation the timer is just a local variable of the MaxTick/MaxTime method and thus you cannot possibly hope to be able to retrieve the time left or time lapsed from it.

Comment: @WimtenBrink You can roll a 13-side dice and get a number from it, which corresponds to the card. In fact, you have D2, which is a **coin flip** (hey, you called it!). As far as I know, a dice and a coin are different.  Just allowing to pass a different value (an integer) with the number of sides could be enough. This way, you can use both an enum and a different value.  Also, here's a set of odd dice (3 to 15): https://www.amazon.com/Green-Unusual-Odd-Numbered-Dice/dp/B00YLWVOXU (source: https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/aroymo/uk_is_there_such_a_thing_as_a_21_sided_dice_and/)